# Detect neovim terminal from bash in bashrc

Tags: terminal, neovim

Does neovim set any environment variables that would let me detect from bash that the terminal is neovim? I want to change the behavior of my `.bashrc` if neovim is the terminal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I compared the output of running `env` in a standard terminal to the output when running it within Neovim, and it looks like these variables are new:

```
VIMRUNTIME=/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/HEAD/share/nvim/runtime
VIM=/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/HEAD/share/nvim
NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/var/folders/_8/sy7jjpw55mbgn2prml0fbsgc0000gn/T/nvimaLHjPR/0
```

(The `vim` I have also has `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` so their mere presence doesn't indicate Neovim vs Vim...)

Answer (score 11):

Aside from alxndr's example, you can set one yourself with:

```
:let $IN_NEOVIM = "yes"
:terminal
$ env | grep NEOVIM
IN_NEOVIM=yes
```

This is especially useful as a simple way to pass information to the shell; for example:

```
:let $NEOVIM_FILETYPE = &filetype
:terminal
$ env | grep NEOVIM
NEOVIM_FILETYPE=python
```